# iPhone - Change entity class (NSManagedObject) to make them initializable

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I would like to use my custom NSManagedObject like a normal object (as well as its regular functions). Is it possible to modify the class in order to be able to initialize it like a normal object?

```
[[myManagedObject alloc] init];
```

Thanks

edit: to clarify the question, will it screw everything up if I change the @dynamic with @synthesize in the implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The managed object context is a required property of NSManagedObject therefore you can't properly initialize an instance of it without inserting it into a context. It looks at the context to understand it its entity and it notifies the context when any of its properties change.

The @dynamic and @synthesize are just compiler directives. You can switch to @synthesize from @dynamic as long as you provide proper getters and setters yourself. Since NSManagedObject relies heavily on key-value observing to function, you do have to write KVO compliant accessors.

If you need to initialize an NSManagedObject subclass, you override `awakeFromInsert` which will let you provide customization to the instance when it is created. You can also customized the object every time it is fetched using `awakeFromFetch`.

Comment: Thanks... it looks clearer now! What I wanted to do is to use these classes outside my persistent storage (like regular objects); which seems impossible

Answer (score 3):

I do this quite often in one of my apps. My approach is to initialize the object with:

```
-(id)initWithEntity:(NSEntityDescription *)entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
```

passing nil for the context. To get the entity description, you do need access to the managedObjectContext. I tend to get the entity description when my app starts and then store it in an instance variable in my app delegate.

Here's an example:

```
//inside my "Engine" class
self.tweetEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Tweet" inManagedObjectContext:self.moc];

//later on when I want an NSManagedObject but not in a managed object context
Tweet *tweet = [[[Tweet alloc] initWithEntity:self.engine.tweetEntity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:nil] autorelease];
```

This allows me to use NSManagedObjects without storing them in a database. Later on, if I decide I do want the object inserted into my database, I can do it by inserting it into my managed object context:

```
[self.moc insertObject:tweet];
```

Comment: The problem is that my entity "Element" has a relationship with the entity "Ingredient" and when I try to use your technic, I try to do element.ingredient = anotherElement.ingredient. I get an error: 'Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'ingredient' between objects in different contexts'

Comment: If the ingredient is stored in a managed object context, then yeah you will have a problem. If the ingredient is also initialized with initWithEntity, then it should work.